# Mysql optimizing date filter

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

Is there any difference in any sql engines (and particularly in mysql) in the following two queries?

```
SELECT * FROM table where date = '2019-01-01'
```

And:

```
SELECT * FROM table where date = DATE('2019-01-01')
```

Doing an `explain` returns the same result, but perhaps there's some sort of difference that I'm not catching? I need to run a query against a multi-billion row table and am trying to optimize it before running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should not be.  The expression `DATE('2019-01-01')` should be evaluated during the compilation phase turning the result into a date.  Similarly, the constant value '2019-01-01' is implicitly converted to a date for the comparison.

This allows MySQL (and most other databases) to use indexes and partitions defined on that column.

Answer (score 0):

Date() function  Extracts the date part of a date or date/time expression

for example the value of the field name BirthTime  is "2017-09-26 16:44:15.581"
so you have to use the following query to check the date :

SELECT DATE(BirthTime)

result is :  2017-09-26